# Submit a parent form with button click on a modal window

Tags: jquery

I have a page which has a save button on click of this button opens a modal window which is basically comprises of an email template where the user has to enter comments and to input fields. There is a send and cancel button on the modal window. If cancel button is clicked it just submits the parent page and doesn't save the email template values for sending email. But if send button is clicked then the email template values for sending the email and the parent page values are submitted. Currently the cancel button functionality is working but send button is not working as expected. Whenever I click send button the page gets hang and doesn't process further. Can anyone help me out with a solution to it.

```
 $("#emailBackBtn").click(function(){               
             var zIndex = 1000 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
             $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);             
            $("#dialog-send").dialog({
                    resizable : false,
                    height : 200,
                    modal : true,
                    closeOnEscape : false,
                    dialogClass : "no-close",   
                    open : function(type, data)
                    {
                        $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index', 9999);
                        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index', zIndex);                        
                    },                     
                    buttons :
                        [
                            {
                                text : "Yes",
                                type : "submit",
                                click : function()
                                {                                       
                                    $(this).dialog("close");    
                                    $('#sendEmailOrPopup').modal('hide');
                                    $("#quotLineEntry").submit();
                                }

                            },
                            {
                                text : "No",
                                type : "button",
                                click : function(){                                     
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            }
                         ]
            });
         });


        $('#emailSendBtn').click(function(){                
             $("#emailCc").val($('#cc').val());
             $("#emailComment").val($('#comment').val());   
             $("#emailTo").val($('#to').val());
             $("#emailBody").val($('#body').html());
             $("#emailSubject").val($('#subject').val());
             $("#emailFrom").val($('#from').val());             
             $("#quotLineEntry").submit();
         });
```

Above are the two buttons functionality in modal window using Jquery. once the send button is click the form is submitted to spring controller.

`#quotLineEntry` is the form present in parent page. `#sendEmailOrPopup` is the modal window.

Comment: Is there any validation on the form in the dialog?   You hide the form before submit, so if submit is failing validation, you won't be able to see the validation.

Comment: Can you clarify "the page hangs and doesn't process further".  There's a *huge* difference between a page not doing anything and the entire browser freezing up.  I'm guessing it just looks like it's not doing anything (ie not hanging at all) - do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: How are handled the form submissions? You cannot submit two forms on the same page unless you are using javascript. Do not close the dialog before submitting the form! Chances are that the form will not be there anymore, since the dialog's content get swept out (i think)

Comment: Hi freedomn-m thanks for ur reply. No there is no validation in the modal. By mentioning the page hangs I mean it doesn't process further somehow the parent form submit doesn't work the page just keeps loading but the control never passes to spring controller. No browser errors in fact it browser console prints any console log till before the last submit function is called.

Comment: Hi Salketer thanks for ur reply. Yes I'm using query to handle form submissions but I'm not submitting two forms only the parent form is getting submitted. Only the values from modal window are stored in an object and is passed along with the parent form attributes to the spring controller function. With cancel it works fine where I just store the parent page values and don't send email whereas with send I store the parent page values and then send a mail with the modal window values passed.